# How do i change the button color in vb.net with an enter action?

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, action

I added a Button *(name: `btn_exit`)* with the action: If *the cursor leaves the button* it should turn red, just as a signal. In my application that doesn't work like i thought. The Console says there no errors. So what do I to adjust to change the color ?

**My Code:**

```
Private Sub btn_exit_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_exit.Leave
    btn_exit.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

Comment: The question should be tagged with the library -- [wpf] or [winforms] -- far more useful than [button] [colors] and [action].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with the 'Leave' event, you have to use the MouseEnter, MouseHover, MouseLeave events.

Example Code (just tested): The button is "normal" until you move the mouse first time over it, then turns to blue and when you leave the mouse then red Background.

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter

    Button1.BackColor = Color.Blue

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave

    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub
```

Comment: your welcome. If this works, please accept my as "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter

  Button1.BackColor = Color.Blue

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave

  Button1.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub
```